# Copy two columns to another table, one is a primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a large table (Visits) with primary key kha_ID.  There are a dozen or so columns in this table and I only want to replace one of them, ADM_SRC.  The problem is that ADM_SRC contains nulls.  I imported another table with the kha_id and that record's corresponding ADM_SRC.  I'm hoping my query below will insert the correct ADM_SRC into the correct record.

Here's my query, I wanted to check out if it'll pass before I run it

```
INSERT INTO tblVisits (kha_id, adm_src)
SELECT (kha_id, adm_src) from tblAdm_Src
```

tblAdm_Src is the imported table.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't explain if you need to insert rows in tblVisits, update rows, or a mixture of both.

Comment: I need to insert the rows into tblVisits.

Comment: So why don't you try it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming

- There's no data in tblVisits
- Id is not an auto-incrementing identity column
- All of the columns have a default value specified

Then your query will work

```
insert into tblVisits (kha_id, adm_src) select kha_id, adm_src from tblAdm_Src
```

If some of the columns don't have default values then you need to supply default values in the query, e.g.

```
insert into tblVisits (kha_id, adm_src, otherColumn) 
select kha_id, adm_src, 'a value' from tblAdm_Src
```

If kha_id is an identity column, you need to use SET IDENTITY_INSERT

```
set identity_insert tblVisits on
insert into tblVisits (kha_id, adm_src) select kha_id, adm_src from tblAdm_Src
set identity_insert tblVisits off
```

If there is existing data in Visit and you need to update matching rows, but insert missing ones then you need something like

```
-- update existing rows
update tblVisits 
    set adm_src = tblAdm_Sr.adm_src
from VisitSource
    where tblVisits.kha_id = tblAdm_Sr.kha_id

-- insert missing rows
insert into tblVisits (kha_id, adm_src) 
select kha_id, adm_src from tblAdm_Src
   where not exists(
     select kha_id from tblVisits where tblVisits.kha_id = tblAdm_Src.kha_id)
```

and of course taking into account default values and auto incrementing Id column as necessary

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to check out if it'll pass before I run it

maybe I do not understand your question in the right way .. but what about

1. truning off auto commit
2. running your query
3. check the result
4. commit (everything went fine) or rollback (not the result as expected)?

Comment: i'm new to sql server and i didn't know that existed/know how to do it :)